# willTransitionToState (UITableViewCell) not called in certain situation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uitextfield

## What I want to achieve

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` featuring a `UITextField` for in-place-editing. A `cell's` field should be enabled while the `UITableView` is in edit mode, but *NOT* while the cell's delete confirmation is showing.

## How I'm achieving it

I've subclassed `UITableViewCell` and overridden its `willTransitionToState` method thusly:

```c
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state {
   [super willTransitionToState:state];
   self.nameField.enabled = !(state & UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask)
                            && (state & UITableViewCellStateEditingMask);
}
```

## The problem

I'm 90% of the way there.

'`willTransitionToState`' is called after the user presses the cell's '-' button. The delete confirmation is shown and my text field is disabled as desired. But what if the user decides not to delete the cell and hides the delete confirmation by swiping right? ***In this case, 'willTransitionToState' is not called.***

As a result, my text field is stuck in its disabled state even though it should be enabled when the delete confirmation is hidden. You would think that given the fact that a '`UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask`' flag exists, that '`willTransitionToState`' would be called symmetrically, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

### UPDATE

It seems that the '`showingDeleteConfirmation`' property of UITableViewCell always gives the correct result. So theoretically I could iterate through each cell calling '`showingDeleteConfirmation`' and enable or disable each text field accordingly. This is inefficient and kludgy. I'm considering filing a bug report on '`willTransitionToState`', but I need more data points. Has anybody else encountered this problem?

#### 4/29/2014

Apple confirms this is a bug. As of today, the bug report is still OPEN.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, any luck?

Comment: I sent a bug report to Apple a month ago. Apple confirms this is indeed a bug--specifically, it is an open, rank 3 "medium" bug whatever that means.

Comment: Exact same issue today. Do you have a link to the bug report with Apple?

Comment: Unfortunately it's only possible to view your own bug reports in Apple's bug report system. My report is listed as a duplicate of report #14645370. For what it's worth, that report is still listed as OPEN.

Comment: Having the exact same issue. iOS 7.1.

Comment: I came to the exact same situation, today, now. You'd thing that the method will be called when the user cancels delete to allow us to renable our contentView. *sighs* iOS 7.1.

Comment: iOS 8.0.2, Xcode 6.0.1.
willTransitionToState: is called, but didTransitionToState: IS NOT.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a context for KVO:

```
static int KVOContext;
```

Get the `scrollView` in the cell with a custom getter:

```
- (UIScrollView *)scrollViewToObserve
{
    UIView *view = self.subviews[0];
    return (view != nil && [view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) ? (UIScrollView *)view : nil;
}
```

Add observer to `scrollView`'s `contentOffset`:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        [self.scrollViewToObserve addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentOffset" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:&KVOContext];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Remove observer in `dealloc`:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [self.scrollViewToObserve removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentOffset" context:&KVOContext];
}
```

Use KVO to observe changes to `contentOffset`, but use `showingDeleteConfirmation` for the `enabled` state:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if (context == &KVOContext) {
        if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"contentOffset"]) {
            self.textField.enabled = !self.showingDeleteConfirmation;
        }
    } else {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
    }
}
```

**Warning**: View hierarchy can change in future updates